# Kibana shared dashboard (iframe) - Filters

Tags: kibana, kibana-5

I'm sharing a dashboard through an iframe.

When i load the iframe in my webapp, is there a way to filter, set the time range or clear existing filters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.
The URL contains all the dashboard state:
visualisation, filters, time range etc...

If you want dashboard with specific time range for example ,you need to embedded the specific URL in your web application.

It's good to know that kibana using "rison" to encoded and decoded URL to JavaScript object

Comment: Yeah, thats not the answer i wanted... hahaha. This way i need to add another widget in my app just to let my users manipulate time, filters and such... Its a shame beacause Kibana its just hiding the topNavBar with the filters when loads as embedded... I will look at the JS,